# NullPointerException while wiring WebDriver by Spring container java

Tags: spring, selenium, nullpointerexception

Hi please help to clarify why i get NullPoint on wiring WebDriver and "PageObject" classes. Have following structure:
   Class Responsible for generating WebDriver

```
@Lazy
@Component
public class WebDriverManager {

    @Lazy
    @Bean
    public WebDriver createDriver(){
        return createGenericDriver();
    }
    public WebDriver createGenericDriver() {//change to system vars
        setProp();

        if (BankConfig.BROWSER.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
            return createFFoxDriver();
        } else if (BankConfig.BROWSER .equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {

            return createChromeDriver();
        } else {
            return createIEDriver();
        }
    }
```

Abstract class with common actiion-methods for all pages:

```
public abstract class AbstractPage {

    protected final WebDriver driver;

    @Autowired
    public AbstractPage(WebDriver beanDriver){

        WebDriverManager.setProp();
        driver=beanDriver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);

    }
    public void init() throws InterruptedException {

        driver.get("www.demo.guru99.com/V4/");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.quit();

    }

}
```

LoginPage:

```
@Lazy
@Component
public class LoginPage extends AbstractPage {

    @Autowired
    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver ) {

        super(driver);

    }
```

and TestClass:

```
public class LoginTest{

    @Autowired
    LoginPage loginPage;


    @Test
    public void test1(){

        try {
            loginPage.init();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Further faced with an error - `java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.GuruBankTestFrame.LoginTest.test1(LoginTest.java:23)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: What does LoginTest.java line 23 look like? Something there does not have a value.